# Galaxy Nexus Android development, how to write date in a file portable to pc

Tags: android, nexus-s

Hi I am a newbie developer on Android. Currently I am developing an app which need to deal with big data, because of the computational cost, ideally I plan to collect data from the phone and send them to a pc.

Special conditions for this case is nexus has no SD card access, also currently I have limited access network which means it is impossible for me to send data over network.

I have searched several example online and it seems that they all operate the data on site the phone using some file iostream. And in my mind, if the file is in the phone, somehow I will get it, but I couldn't! and no tutorials online clearly point out the places for the created data files.

Can someone give me some help on how to get data to a pc? Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are able to create file then the path would be

if root-package mentioned in AndroidManifest.xml is for example: a.b.c

then you will get the file somewhere here
/data/data/a.b.c/
try using adb mount, pull commands to get the file.

Comment: thank you so much! I got it following your help. Really helpful